# FTP Setup - Grant permission only current directory

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, ftp

I have a Ubuntu server setup with ProFTP

How can I grant access to only a certain directory, but NOT any of its subdirectories?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the user and group that the server normally runs at.

Group:users
User1
User2

\data1\sub1

Set owner of /data1 group:users
Set owner of /sub1 owner:user2 group:user2

Comment: Thanks @user1261959. I'm a bit new to this. How do I check or change the use/group that the server normally runs at?